# grep for exact match

Tags: linux, grep

I have a file that looks like this:

```
1   2HE MET 1.8493
1   3HE MET 1.3568
2   H   GLN 6.1731
2   HA  GLN 4.2384
2   2HB GLN 2.2204
2   3HB GLN 1.3062
```

I use the grep command: `grep H file` and get all the lines as shown above. I would like to only retrieve the line `2   H   GLN 6.1731`.
I've used `grep 'H$'file` as well as `grep -x H processed_shifts.out` but do not get any output with these commands. How could I modify the grep command to only get line 3 as the output?

Comment: Use the `-w`/`--word-regexp` option to match only whole words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using GNU grep then you can use the `-w` or `--word-regexp` flag, or wrap the regex with word boundaries:

```
grep '\bH\b'
```

However, this will be non-portable, since POSIX grep lacks the `-w` flag and neither basic nor extended regular expressions support word boundaries. So if you wish for the command to be portable then you'll have to do something like

```
grep ' H '
```

or otherwise use a more powerful language, like AWK:

```
awk '$2=="H" { print }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using regular expressions with grep. Try using /^H$/ as what you are grepping. This is the regular expression for an exact match on H. the ^ means the string must start with H and the $ means it must end in H. therefore it will match for any string that is just H.

let me know if that works, as I am unable to test my answer at this moment.

Comment: `^` matches the start of the line. Similarly `$` matches the end of the line. Neither of those anchors is valid for the case in question.

Comment: Dang, your right. I haven't used regular expressions in awhile, so I'm a bit rusty.

Comment: The `\b`, `\<`, and `\>` escapes match word boundaries and could be used here but `-w` is simpler.

Comment: Try using .*\sH\s.* That should match any line that contains H by itself.
*I was too slow:P

Comment: And won't match an `H` at the start or end of the line. There's a reason the boundary escapes exist.